# Wifi disconnect randomly 5 or 10 times per day without reason

Tags: wireless, server, dmesg

I have a Intel NUC NUC6I3SYH that has on board an Intel Core i3-6100U and an Intel Wireless-AC 8260 M.2 welded on main board. I installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS two mounths ago and everything was ok. This miniPC is used as server for some industrial application, and is connected by LAN to internet and uses wifi connection to be connected in an private net, completely disconnected from internet.
There are 7 script in python running on it interacting with mysql server and TCPmodbus units using the internal private network. 
Since last week the connection between the NUC and the router wifi is affected by micro disconnection: analizing the logs of my scripts I can understand that the disconnection ha duration of less then 20seconds. 
I checked the wifi log using dmesg but nothing seems to show me that there was a real disconnection.
Ho can I get deeper level logging for wifi? or do you have some idea about this issue?
Is seems just like if the system reached some kind of saturation, but I don't know how to demonstrate it.
Thank you very much in advance